# Using an additional column with large number of categories to plot in bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with 3 columns: Violation_Location, Violation_Code and Ticket_Frequency. However, there are several categories (i.e., more than 100 each) in both the Violation_Code and Violation_Location columns.

I would like to get the top 10 of both the Violation_Location and Violation_Code based on ticket frequencies.

```
Precint = spark.sql("SELECT Violation_Location, Violation_Code, Count(*) as Ticket_Frequency from table_view2 group by Violation_Location, Violation_Code order by Ticket_Frequency desc")
Precint.show()
```

```
Violation_Location|Violation_Code|Ticket_Frequency|
+------------------+--------------+----------------+
|              null|            36|         1098296|
|              null|             7|          471754|
|              null|             5|          248774|
|                18|            14|          132123|
|               114|            21|           84051|
|                14|            14|           83664|
|                19|            46|           82640|
|                14|            69|           69006|
```

So far, i can only manage to plot the top 10 Violation_Location based on Ticket_Frequency. Any form of help is appreciated, thank you!

```
# plot violation based on the states the cars were registered to
precintplot = Precint.toPandas()
plt.figure(figsize=(100,200))

#remove missing rows from Violation_Location first
precintplotnomiss = precintplot.dropna(subset=['Violation_Location'])
precintplotnomiss.head(10).plot(x='Violation_Location', y='Ticket_Frequency', kind='bar')
plt.title("Violations by Precint (top 10)")
plt.xlabel('Precint')
plt.ylabel('Ticket Frequency')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe I have missed it, but what is your question or problem?

Comment: So far i have plotted the top 10 Violation_Locations based on Ticket_Frequencies. I would like to add in the Violation_Codes as categories within the Violation_Location column

Comment: Can you please add an image which shows your expected diagram?